# Error al loguear varias cuentas desde una aplicacion en c#

Tags: c#

Se que es complicado de explicar mi problema es el siguiente encontre un programa open source para autenticar cuentas pero me da un error:

Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' en mscorlib.dll

Información adicional: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

La parte del código que marca cuando se produce el fallo:

```
 #region Account Login: Single
            string AN = AccountTxt.Text;
            AnimationDisplay = string.Format("Logging In% | {0}", AN);
            AnimationTmr.Start();
            if (AN.Contains("@"))
            {
                Program.Emails[AN].BeginLogin(new AsyncCallback((iAr) =>
                {
                    HSession HS = (HSession)iAr.AsyncState;

                    if (HS.EndLogin(iAr))
                    {
                        Program.Accounts[HS.PlayerName] = HS;
                        Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            AccountTxt.Items.Remove(HS.Email);
                            AccountTxt.Items.Add(HS.PlayerName);
                            AccountTxt.SelectedIndex = AccountTxt.Items.IndexOf(HS.PlayerName);
                        }));
                        DisplayFinish("Login Success! | " + AN);
                    }
                    else
                        DisplayFinish("Login Failed! | " + AN);
                }), Program.Emails[AN]);
            }
            else
            {
                Program.Accounts[AN].BeginLogin(new AsyncCallback((iAr) =>
                {
                    DisplayFinish(string.Format("Login {0}! | {1}", (iAr.AsyncState as HSession).EndLogin(iAr) ? "Success" : "Failed", AN));
                }), Program.Accounts[AN]);
            }
            #endregion
```

Lo que quiere decir es que lo incluya al diccionario pero a cual o mas o menos si sacais alguna conclusión comentarmela. Lamento de nuevo esta molestia. Si necesitan más codigo lo compartire. Repito lamentos las molestia.
Y es solo que quiero loguear varias cuentas desde c# pero necesito saber como incluirlas al programa.

> Buscar todos "program.emails", Subcarpetas, Mantener archivos modificados abiertos, Resultados de la búsqueda 1, Toda la solución, ""
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(59):                if (HS != null && !Program.Emails.ContainsKey(HS.Email))
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(61):                    Program.Emails[HS.Email] = HS;
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(99):                        Program.Emails[Account].BeginLogin(new AsyncCallback((iAr) =>
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(116):                        }), Program.Emails[Account]);
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(140):                    Program.Emails[AN].BeginLogin(new AsyncCallback((iAr) =>
>     C:\Users\android\Desktop\K3ND4X-Silver 3d1tion\Kendax-master\Kendax\Main.cs(156):                    }), Program.Emails[AN]);
>     Líneas coincidentes: 6    Archivos coincidentes: 1    Archivos examinados: 57
>     Se ha detenido el proceso de búsqueda.

Comment: cual seria el diccionario que genera el problema este Program.Emails[AN] o este Program.Accounts[HS.PlayerName] ?

Comment: el AN es lo que obtengo de lo que tengo guardado en el combobox. es complcado de entender. formule mal la pregunta. disculpa las molestias.Puedes revisar más parte del codigo.

Comment: en que parte del codigo generas las entradas del dictionary Program.Emails ? de que tipo es el dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Para validar y agregar una key inexistente al diccionario podrias usar

```
if(Program.Accounts.ContainsKey(HS.PlayerName))
    Program.Accounts[HS.PlayerName] = HS;
else
    Program.Accounts.Add(HS.PlayerName, HS);
```

[Dictionary.ContainsKey Method (TKey)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: pero en que parte del codigo lo incluyo dentro y como agrego la key un saludo me parece que la solución que me diste esta muy cerca de resolver mi problema

Comment: Yo pienso necesito incluir los datos de mi combobox a un diccionario para hacerlo funcionar creo

Comment: @OmarAlami en el codigo no veo que uses ningun combobox, si hay un textbox AccountTxt.Text. Puedes incluir a key al diccionario, pero como generas el value ?

Comment: el value es los items del combobox los almaceno en la variable.  [AN]

Comment: el value lo genero colocandome en el formulario, dandole en combobox y luego añadir item

Comment: @OmarAlami la verdad no entiendo que quieres lograr, si lo items del dictionary<> lo defines en otro sitio entonces sino encuentras una key es correcto que falle, quizas debas usar el TryGetValue() para intentar obtner un valor y sino esta poder informarlo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: falla porque no encuentra la key necesito saber como colocarla en el codigo. He incluido otra mensaje de error que me sale en el depurador de visual studio. Lamento las molstias de nuevo y gracias por su paciencia. Un saludo. Lo que quiero que coja el email para loguearme

Comment: El tema es que cuando tu llegas aqui Program.Emails[AN].BeginLogin(new AsyncCallback((iAr) =>... ya tienes un valor para esa key, cuando no la encuentra podrias generarla, pero que value le asignarias ? no veo de donde tomas el valor para asignar a la key que no encuentra.

Comment: el value es la password

Comment: @OmarAlami pero para cuando quieres agregar la key que no existe no tienes el dato del password que debes asignar a esa key inexistente en el diccionario, no se si me explico. cuando armas el diccionario asignando las key y sus valores tiene la correspondencia entre estas, pero cuando estas en la operacion de trabjar con los datos si la key no existe, de donde tomas el password ? tiene ese valor para asignar a la key en ese momento?